# Generic math notation for minimum/maximum

Tags: notation, index-notation

Where finding the `minimum` or `maximum` element of a vector depends on the sign of those values, how can I avoid two time separated description in mathematics?

Is it ok using some convention similar to Optimization problem definition, like below:

let's V be a vector that can have either positive and negative values;

```
x = sgn(V[argmax|V|]) max(V)
```

so if the element having maximum absolute value in V is a negative value, the function should calculate minimum rather than maximum.

is it correct in math notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematical notation, your formula is
$$
x = \operatorname{sgn}(v_{\arg\max\{\lvert v_i\rvert : v_i\in V\}}) \max V.
$$
Notice that if the most negative element of $V$ has a larger magnitude than the most positive element, your formula uses the *sign* of the most negative element to determine the result, but it does not use the *magnitude* of the most negative element.

You could fix your original formula by introducing more absolute values,
$$
x = \operatorname{sgn}(v_{\arg\max\{\lvert v_i\rvert : v_i\in V\}})
       \max\{\lvert v_i\rvert : v_i\in V\},
$$
but I think a far more elegant solution is just to explicitly list the two cases in which you're interested:
$$
x = \begin{cases} \max V & \lvert\max V\rvert \geq \lvert\min V\rvert, \\
\min V & \lvert\max V\rvert < \lvert\min V\rvert. \\
\end{cases}
$$

Note that you have to decide what to do if the two extreme values in the vector are equal in magnitude and opposite in sign. I chose to set $x$ to the positive value in that case, but you could choose differently. You could even make this a third case of your definition with a different behavior from either of the other two cases.

(Note that the case where there are equal and opposite values in $V$ is problematic for the formula with $\arg\max$, because that formula doesn't say whether to take the positive or negative value in that case.)

Comment: Thank you very much David for your perfect answer, suggestion and reply. As you noticed correctly, I just wanted to see if it is correct to use the convention of `-min = max` for such case as my example. I take you suggestion. Cheers!